# How to send file content in distributed environment?

Tags: java, file, activemq-classic, distributed

I have the following scenario:

Two Java applications use **ActiveMQ** for communication.They use a publisher/subscription model.

One application has some physical files, and the other one should request the file content. What is the best way of sending the file?
**One idea** should be reading the file in memory in a **byte array** and to serializate the array, and send the file content in a **message**.
Do you have any other ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Another idea is making the applications share the filesystem (i.e. share the subtree where that physical files are created) with NFS, sshfs, samba, etc., so it's enough to send a file *name*. Yet another idea is to use another protocol for sending files outside of rabbitmq (like building an ftp server into one of your applications).

Comment: Depends how big your files is? If they are not so big, then yeah you can transfer them as JMS messages. If big files, you can use off-band. See this link also: http://activemq.apache.org/can-i-send-really-large-files-over-activemq.html

Comment: @ClausIbsen You gave me a good idea. Could you post this as an answer so I can give you the full credit?

Comment: @AntonKovalenko I would like to get rid off all constraints that come with making the application share the filesystem. The system should be click to deploy. Regarding the size of the file, those should not be big, but they are created frequently, and sent often. I don't think a ftp server would help me. But thank you for answering me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends how big your files is? If they are not so big, then yeah you can transfer them as JMS messages.

If big files, you can use off-band. See this link also:

- http://activemq.apache.org/can-i-send-really-large-files-over-activemq.html

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the normal ways to distribute a file. I would not suggest using ways to transfer the whole file (email, copy, enclos the file in a message) but this depends on the usage of the file. Sharing a file would probably be the simplest and most efficient solution. You should also take into account, what are you going to do with this file. Do you want it to be randomly accessed? Do you really need to trasfer it as a whole?

You could also consider using [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/). Hadoop is a distributed system's framework which is oriented towards highly localized data. It also gives you have a distributed file system (HFS).

Hope I helped!

Comment: The system must be closed. I can't use "normal ways" of distributing the file, because the process **MUST** be transparent for the user, and fast. Also, for now I can send messages (not Instant Messages, but data from a broker to another), but I was looking at an easier way of sending files. Regarding Hadoop, thanks for the suggestion, but in my situation, it could be bigger in setup and space than my entire project. :D. Neverless, I thank you for suggesstions.